# Silverlight loading screen goes direct from 0% to 100%

Tags: silverlight, loading, progress

I have a silverlight app that uses the default startup loading progress bar. It used to start from 0% and gradually move to 100%. Some days ago, I did a minor update to the xap file and since then, it loads by staying at 0% for a long time and then suddenly it loads, that is, it no longer shows the loading progress. I tested it on several computers and browsers and the same thing happens. I am concerned as some users may think the app has frozen. Any idea how to correct this?

EDIT: I find that if I place the xap file on another web server, the progress bar works.

Comment: What was the minor update? Do you see the progress bar if you undo the changes?

Comment: I made some code changes like modifying a mathematical formula. I will not be able to undo the changes for the time being. I have updated the question as I find that I don't get the problem if I put the xap file on another web server.

Comment: What happens if you clear your browser's cache? It may be down to the web server's config. In particular, perhaps it's doing Chunk Encoding and not sending Content-Length. Use a packet sniffer to check. Btw, "I will not be able to undo the changes" is a horrible thing to say. Use a version control system. I recommend Git (although it's a bit complex and the GUI tools, even third-party ones, aren't super-friendly).

Comment: Same thing if I undo the changes or clear the browser cache or use another browser. The server does send the content-length. I presume it is a server specific issue since the application works well on other servers. Unfortunately, I don't manage the servers.

Comment: Hmm. Compare the headers the two servers send carefully, or post them in your question. I'm surprised Content-Length is not at fault, but it must be something in the headers.